# Send blind calls to voicemail?

Tags: cyanogenmod, call-screening

I'm getting more and more blind calls on my cellphone from telemarketers.

Is there an application that can send all incoming blind calls to voicemail?

FWIW, I'm running Cyanogenmod on a Galaxy Nexus.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you really need an app for that? AFAIK there's a "call block handler" integrated with the dialer, where you can blacklist numbers. If you insist on an app, please remember that *Is there an app for X* questions are listed as being off-topic (see our [help/on-topic] for details). A playstore search for "call blocker" (better [done at AppBrain](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=call%20blocker) as GPlay got quite limited) will present you with a mass of apps to chose from.

Comment: By blind, do you mean all Unknown/Blocked-ID numbers, or any number that isn't in your address list? "blind" is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: I don't know the correct term: I meant people calling as "hidden number", ie. I don't know who's calling. I want all such calls to be automatically forwarded to voicemail.

Answer (score 2):

I just saw that you don't want to block the calls, but send to voicemail.
My mistake.

---

As easy as one, two, three :)

Call settings -> Blacklist -> Small icon at the bottom corner -> Private numbers

[image: block-private-numbers-image]

That is for cm-10.2.0

Might be a little different if you have another version, but you get the idea.