# How can I send incoming calls from unknown numbers directly to voicemail?

Tags: calls, 6.0-marshmallow, call-screening, caller-id

I have received incoming calls from an unknown number (no caller ID provided). When I answer, I get a recording which is clearly spam. Is there a way to send calls from an unknown number directly to voicemail so that my phone does not ring?

This is very similar to [Call blocking with spoken message?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8435/call-blocking-with-spoken-message?lq=1), but I do not need a new message to play. Regular voicemail is fine.

I am interested in a solution for stock Android 6.0 Marshmallow. There appears to be the ability to block calls in CyanogenMod, which would be suboptimal, but I cannot find a similar setting in Marshmallow, either in Settings or in the Call application settings. [Send blind calls to voicemail?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/57599/send-blind-calls-to-voicemail)

This is different from blocking a known number, as in
[How can I reliably screen or block callers on a number-by-number basis?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9977/how-can-i-reliably-screen-or-block-callers-on-a-number-by-number-basis)

This is different from [How to block private numbers](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/129694/how-to-block-private-numbers) because I do not want to block calls, just send them to voicemail, and this option is not available on stock Marshmallow. The call application allows blocking specific numbers but not unknown numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to block private numbers](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/129694/how-to-block-private-numbers)

Comment: If you can describe under what conditions your voice mail gets activated it would be good, like for example, on call rejection, call not answered in xx second our anything else...This is specific to your carrier

Comment: @beeshyams I believe calls got to voicemail both when rejected and after xx seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Automation is the preferred option. Many apps are available. I prefer using [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) , since it is free (upto 5 macros) and easy to learn. To understand how MacroDroid works and the **settings** required for your Android version, see  my [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/130619/remote-manage-the-wifi-connection)

**Note**

1. This is not tested on Marshmallow  as I am on KitKat
2. You will need to tweak timings in accordance with voicemail behaviour and "Doze" feature of Marshmallow
3. Voice mail is used solely for unknown callers
4. This solution also "mutes" unknown callers (no call ring sound) before diverting them to voicemail to minimise spam nuisance

Your macros would look like this

- **Unknown caller macro**

**Trigger**: *Call incoming* → *Select contact* →*Unknown Caller*

**Actions**:

- *Volume Change* →*Ringer* (Set to zero on sliding scale- this action will mute ringer for unknown caller)
- *Call Reject*
- *Wait before next action* (set time in seconds per voicemail behaviour so that call is sent to voicemail)

**Constraints**: *None*

- **Other caller macro** (to reverse muting of call done for unknown callers)

**Trigger**:

*Call incoming* → *Select contact* →*Any number*

**Action**:

*Volume Change* →*Ringer* (Set to required volume on sliding scale- this action will unmute ringer for callers other than unknown caller)

**Constraints**: *None*

Comment: You can test with any landline number by choosing that as a contact. Also can change order of wait for xx seconds and call reject. This has the advantage of ensuring both happen so that at least one of them Will start voice mail