# How can I auto-send all calls (not in my contact list) on Galaxy S20 (Verizon) to Voice Mail without ringing?

Tags: samsung, contacts, verizon, call-screening, voicemail

I have a Samsung Galaxy S20 (Verizon) phone. Contacts that I blocked create new telephone numbers online to call me constantly. I want my normal unblocked contacts to ring (family, friends, doctors, others). My goal is for all numbers not in my contact list to go to voice mail before the ring. So I can use my device normally without the distraction of unknown callers.

Research shows:

- Airplane Mode inhibits the full use of my phone.
- Do not Disturb limits my notifications.
- Spam blockers do not block the new numbers people create.
- Premium voice mail only works on a known contact (I have this).
- Block from the phone or the website only works on a known contact number.
- Setting a ringtone only works on a contact already in the list.
- Changing my number is only temporary so not an option.

Many solutions have to do with a known number to manipulate. An unknown number is the bane of my existence. Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts. Looks like there's an existing Q&A about the same problem: [How can I send incoming calls from unknown numbers directly to voicemail?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/133071/44325). Consider trying the answer and let us know the result. Thanks.

Comment: The question is the same but the solution given sends all calls to voicemail. I would like my contacts to ring and if I do not answer, have them sent to voicemail.  I would like all other calls, not listed in my contact list to go to voice mail.  My x creates new phone numbers to contact me.  76 calls right after another.  sending non contacts directly to voicemail before the ring stops 6 hours of harassment ringing.  PFA's, harassment charges, and changing my number does not stop it.  I;m open to a pay service too.  looking for a solution.